# Is there any way to check if text in an entry field was loaded in using the .set() function or was typed by the user?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create an autocomplete function for a few entry fields, however when I enter some text and select an autocomplete suggestion, the automatic loading of text into the other entry fields causes said entry fields' auto-complete functions to fire off as well, leading to a circle of autocompletion.

So, I would want to detect if the text being entered into the entry field was typed up or loaded in by the .set() function.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in. You can set up your own triggers to set a flag the first time a user presses a key, however.

Or, if you're just trying to stop some behavior when you programatically insert text, set a flag, insert the text, and then unset the flag.